# Why isn't animate() working in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, jquery-animate

I must be missing something stupid.  I don't think it's a syntax error, but it could be I suppose.  My suspicion is that I have left something out of the formatting in CSS that's preventing it from working, but I have no clue what.

Here's the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/gQUu2/

```
//html
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <p>some text</p>
        <div class="logo_effect"></div>
    </div>
</body>


//css
.logo
{
    margin: 50px;
    width: 190px;
}

.logo p
{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
}

.logo_effect
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
```

}

```
//jquery
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.logo').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: Syntax error. Also, you forgot to select jquery http://jsfiddle.net/gQUu2/

Comment: Check your console, please.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing paren `)`. The following code works for me (when altering your jsFiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.logo').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0);
    });
});
```